# Is it possible to stop IntelliJ adding @private in jsdoc comments?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jsdoc

If I have a private function in a javascript file:

```
Class.prototype._method = function () {
   // do stuff
};
```

When I start a doc block IntelliJ will helpfully stub it out, so I get:

```
/**
 * 
 * @private
 */
Class.prototype._method = function () {
```

I already have [JsDoc](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/) configured to treat underscored functions as private so I would rather it was **not** added in the comment.  Is it possible to configure IntelliJ so it doesn't add `@private` in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It should already work in the latest IDEA version, see the [resolved request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76545).</strike>

Note that it's added on stub generation, when you type `/**` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: That request is for it to add the `@private` comment - I'd like to turn this off.

Comment: Sorry, it was probably too late and I've completely missed "stop" and "not" words in your question. In any way, it's not possible. Feel free to submit a request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA.